# Current time -1 hour

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following column that is made using the following function

```
to_char(to_date(f.f_sto_sta_dt_id, 'YYYYMMDD') + (f.f_sto_sta_ti_id/86400), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as sto_sta dt_cur
```

T1

```
f_sto_sta_dt_id  f_sto_sto_dt_id(number format)  f_sto_sta_ti_id(number format)  sto_sta_dr_cur sto_sto_dt_cur
    20191001           20191001          7789            7822                         02:09:49      02:10:22
```

I would like to add 2 columns where I convert the `sto_sta_dr_cur` and `sto_sto_dt_cur` to UTC time.

The `sto_sta_dr_cur` and `sto_sto_dt_cur` are in `CET` time format.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( f_sto_sta_dt_id, f_sto_sto_dt_id, f_sto_sta_ti_id, f_sto_sto_ti_id ) AS
SELECT 20191001, 20191001, 7789, 7822 FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT FROM_TZ(
         TO_TIMESTAMP( TO_CHAR( f_sto_sta_dt_id ), 'YYYYMMDD' )
           + NUMTODSINTERVAL( f_sto_sta_ti_id, 'SECOND' ),
         'CET'
       ) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS sto_sta_dt_cur,
       FROM_TZ(
         TO_TIMESTAMP( TO_CHAR( f_sto_sto_dt_id ), 'YYYYMMDD' )
           + NUMTODSINTERVAL( f_sto_sto_ti_id, 'SECOND' ),
         'CET'
       ) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS sto_sto_dt_cur
FROM   test_data
```

**Output**:

> ```
> STO_STA_DT_CUR                    | STO_STO_DT_CUR                   
> :-------------------------------- | :--------------------------------
> 2019-10-01 00:09:49.000000000 UTC | 2019-10-01 00:10:22.000000000 UTC
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7aa5005d9b6c040dcd097d16b3a41ed0)*